# como hacer el parametro de la funcion un String

Tags: javascript, html5

hola estoy tratando de generar una tabla pero al hacer que el parametro de la funcion sea texto he tenido muchos problemas este es el codigo:

```
 elemento = elemento +'</br>'+'<span onclick="borrar('+libros[i].autores[j]+');">'+libros[i].autores[j]+'</span>';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me lo genera de esa manera y deberia de ser: "Jhon Stamos" como String en el parametro

ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es por las concatenaciones, debes de tener en cuenta cuando es necesario las comillas simples y las comillas dobles.

```
 elemento = elemento +'</br>'+"<span 
 onclick="+'"'+"borrar("+"'" +libros[i].autores[j]+"'" +")" 
 +'"'+">" +libros[i].autores[j]+'</span>';
```

Comment: eso ya lo habia intentado pero no sirve me lo genera asi:

<span onclick="borrar(" jhon="" stamos');'="">Jhon Stamos</span>
 asi genera el elemento en html

Comment: elemento = elemento +'</br>'+"<span 
 onclick="+'"'+"borrar("+'"'+libros[i].autores[j]+'"' +");" +'"'+">" +libros[i].autores[j]+'</span>';

Comment: Prueba eso, estoy desde el móvil, así que no puedo hacerlo en el pc, para verlo bien como saldria, pero así debería de ir bien.

Comment: es que ya lo intente pero igual no funciona... cuando lo pongo me marca error en la cabecera como si no cerrara una } y no puede ser otra cosa por que si quito lo que me pusiste ya no lo marca

con lo que me diste genera el codigo asi:

https://ibb.co/hbsaf6

Comment: elemento = elemento +'</br>'+"<span 
 onclick="+'"'+"borrar("+"'" +libros[i].autores[j]+"'"  +")" +'"'+">" 
 +libros[i].autores[j]+'</span>';

Comment: He quitado el ; y cambiado las comillas de dentro para que fueran simples, a ver si ahora si, en la foto que has puesto, estaba ya casi.

Comment: ya!! muchisimas gracias me tenia como loco ese problema